# Generic method causes "cannot pass immutable value of type AnyObject? as inout argument"

Tags: swift, generics, immutability, anyobject

I'm working on a Swift version of a Keychain wrapper class. I'm a bit puzzled why this works:

```
private func executeFetch(query: KeyStoreObject) throws -> AnyObject? {
    var result: AnyObject?
    try executeQuery(query) { SecItemCopyMatching(query.data, &result) }
    return result
}
```

And this doesn't:

```
private func executeFetch<T: AnyObject>(query: KeyStoreObject) throws -> T? {
    var result: T?
    try executeQuery(query) { SecItemCopyMatching(query.data, &result) }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the error is that `SecItemCopyMatching` may attempt to assign anything of type `AnyObject` (i.e. anything at all) to `result`. However, in the second example `result` is not necessarily of type `AnyObject`; it is some particular type `T` that is a subclass of `AnyObject`. Thus, `SecItemCopyMatching` may be unable to correctly set `result`. For instance, what if `T` is `Int`, but `SecItemCopyMatching` wants to set `result` to a `String`? When `result` is of type `AnyObject` this is no longer an issue.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, basically I'm limiting SecItemCopyMatching in returning any object type.